# Ran into this error while trying to create a CI/CD pipeline for AWS using Github Actions

Tags: amazon-web-services, github-actions, cicd

I ran into the following error while trying to create a CI/CD pipeline for a .NET Core project using Github Actions.

[Related image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fI9DZ.png)

Can someone explain how to resolve this? Been stuck here for quite some time and I could only find PowerShell references to this error online.

[edit]:
Made the changes as suggested but now I get this error.
I don't get which file the system is trying to find.

[Related image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fYE5.png)

Comment: Did you try to change the line to something like: `docker build -t ${ECR_REGISTRY}/${ECR_REPOSITORY}:${IMAGE_TAG} .`

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the colon within two powershell variables. You have to change the line in you powershell script to this:

```
docker build -t ${ECR_REGISTRY}/${ECR_REPOSITORY}:${IMAGE_TAG} .
```

I tried it with this simple powershell script:

```
$Variable1 = "Hello"
$Variable2 = "world"

Write-Host $Variable1:$Variable2
```

When running this script, I get the same error message like in your picture. Changing the script to the following

```
$Variable1 = "Hello"
$Variable2 = "world"

Write-Host ${Variable1}:${Variable2}
```

the script runs without any errors.